# What am I doing wrong with this derivative? (Product rule & derivative of arctan)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is my first time posting here, so sorry if I don't get the formatting right!

For my Calc 2 pretest, this was one of the questions:

Let $f(x)=\mathrm{x^3}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{tan^{-1} (2x)}$

Find $f'(x)$

Here is what I did to attempt to solve the problem. First, applying the product rule:

$$f'(x)=\mathrm{x^3}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\frac{d}{dx}[tan^{-1}(2x)]} + \mathrm{tan^{-1}(2x)}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)}$$

\mathrm{u}!\cdot!\mathrm{v}

Second, I am applying the chain rule and the derivative of $tan^{-1}(x)$ to simplify the first addend, and then applying the power rule to find the derivative of $x^3$.

$$f'(x)=\mathrm{x^3}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\frac1{1+(2x)^2}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\frac{d}{dx}[2x]} + \mathrm{tan^{-1}(2x)}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{3x^2}$$

Next up, using the power rule to find the derivative of $2x$ and then the calculus part will be done:

$$f'(x)=\mathrm{x^3}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\frac1{1+(2x)^2}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{2} + \mathrm{tan^{-1}(2x)}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{3x^2}$$

Now I simplify and get that $f'(x)=$

$$\frac{2x^3}{1+4x^2}+3x^2tan^{-1}(2x)$$

But the problem is this wasn't one of the answers! I did it again and again and kept getting this answer, but no matter what I tried I couldn't manipulate the above expression to match one of my multiple choice answers. I ended up guessing wrong and losing points on the pretest, but I am not able to see what the correct answer is. Hopefully someone can tell me where I went wrong!

Comment: Where were the choices?

Comment: everything looks fine, what the options?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to go back and see the choices now that the exam is over. I had the foresight to make sure I had copied down the problem correctly, but not the answer choices, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you remember if any of the answers were written in a factored form?

Comment: No answers were written in factored form (that was the first thing I looked for when I noticed my answer wasn't there). All of them were written using the same form as my answer, but slightly different. For example, one that I recall replaced 2x^3 with x^3 and 4x^2 with 2x^2, but otherwise was the same. All except one had the same thing for the second addend as I had, but different for the first.

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: $\frac{x^3}{.5+2x^2}+3x^2 \tan^{-1}(2x)$  maybe that was a choice? lol It's hard to guess what their choices look like.

Comment: Your answer is very correct.